# Get the row with maximum nested table entries

Tags: sql, count, nested, aggregate-functions

I have a nested table in a object database. Now I want that row, that has the most rows in the nested table.

[image: Table example]

The problem is, I don't have a object database, but I have to learn some SQL statements for a exam. For now my query looks like this:

```
SELECT o.Order_Number   
FROM Order o, TABLE(o.Position) pos  
GROUP BY o.Order_Number  
HAVING COUNT (*) >= all  
(SELECT COUNT(*)   
FROM pos);
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your sample data doesn't look much like a traditional relational table.

Answer (score 0):

With `ANSI` `SQL` for most DBs you can use a little trickery with the `RANK()` function

```
SELECT Order_Number, Order_Count
FROM (
    SELECT Order_Number, COUNT(1) Order_Count,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC) Ranking
    FROM [Position]
    GROUP BY Order_Number
) a
WHERE Ranking = 1
```